# Puppeteer and browserless/chrome docker container connectcion with {headless: false} propertie

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, puppeteer

I am able to connect to Chrome running on port 3000 on Docker with Puppeteer, but even though I use the {headless: true} parameter, I cannot see the browser. This parameter works for the launch function but I cannot connect to the Docker Chrome with the launch function, and I am not sure if it actually works for the connect function, so how can i see the Chrome running on Docker with Puppeteer.

Docker code: `run -d -p 3000:3000 --name browserless --shm-size 2gb -e "MAX_CONCURRENT_SESSIONS=10" -e DISPLAY=:99 --restart always browserless/chrome`

Node.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async  () => {
    try {
        browser = await puppeteer.connect({
            headless: false,
            browserWSEndpoint: 'ws://localhost:3000',
        });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://www.google.com/');
        await page.evaluate(() => {
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})();
```

Comment: "even though I use the {headless: true} parameter, I cannot see the browser" -- do you mean `{headless: false}`? When the browser is headless, you should expect it to be invisible.

Comment: But only when i use a parameter in the launch function, a chrome window is opened:
await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        executablePath: 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe',
      });

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Did you solve this @ReşitAbdullahYavuzkol? I'm having the same issue. Very annoying as this seems like table stakes functionality for Browserless